# Identify book about 2 humanoid aliens stranded on Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

First read this as a loan from Galashiels Public Library in 1970s.

Basic plot: 2 humanoid aliens are stranded on Earth. The male becomes the subject of an investigation by a young female newspaper reporter. The female marries an engineer in the Space Program. She uses sex to extract information from him, as she is desperate to return home. I won't spoil the ending.

I think it was a yellow jacket cover, but I might well be wrong.

Comment: You can spoil the end it if you use the spoiler protection you can find [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Go ahead and spoil it. Spoilers are expected in story-identification questions; withholding information is frowned on.

Comment: Yellow jacket? Was it a [Gollancz](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/gollancz) book? That would narrow it down. Here's a [gallery](http://sf-encyclopedia.uk/gallery.php?list&filter=gollancz) of  lots of their covers, including many from the 70s and before. [This page](http://www.sfgateway.com/books/) has a link to a spreadsheet of just their current titles, all 3357 of them.